# Windows 8.1 Live Tile

Tags: feature-request

How many people would like to see their favorite site with a Windows 8.1 Live Tile?

I know I would.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
    <msapplication>
        <tile>
            <square70x70logo src="tiny.png"/>
            <square150x150logo src="square.png"/>
            <wide310x150logo src="wide.png"/>
            <square310x310logo src="large.png"/>
            <TileColor>#000000</TileColor>
        </tile>
        <notification>
            <polling-uri src="http://notifications.buildmypinnedsite.com/?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds&amp;id=1"/>
            <polling-uri2 src="http://notifications.buildmypinnedsite.com/?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds&amp;id=2"/>
            <polling-uri3 src="http://notifications.buildmypinnedsite.com/?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds&amp;id=3"/>
            <polling-uri4 src="http://notifications.buildmypinnedsite.com/?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds&amp;id=4"/>
            <polling-uri5 src="http://notifications.buildmypinnedsite.com/?feed=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds&amp;id=5"/>
            <frequency>30</frequency>
            <cycle>1</cycle>
        </notification>
    </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer chrome and a bookmark. Otherwise it's two tiles for chrome and it's unfair for the other tiles.

Comment: I must admit I haven't used windows 8.1 but can you not create links to websites on the start page?

Comment: @RichardTingle: You can, but you can also add code to your webpage to create a live tile that shows, e.g., the top three hot questions.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeAWindows81PinnedLiveTileForYOURWebsiteInMinutes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not to say what you have isn't cool, but you can do [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2762879?hl=en) already:

[image]

Admittedly, it doesn't look as nice as yours but I don't like the tile screen anyways.